# Не работает бот на python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте есть бот(Не мой)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
import json
import collections
 
 
#номер упражнения и куки
rule_id = "??????"
cookie  = "PHPSESSID=?????????????????????"
 
#заголовки пакетов
headers = {"Host": "gramotei.cerm.ru",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0",
           "Accept": "*/*",
           "Accept-Language": "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
           "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
           "DNT": "1",
           "Referer": "http://gramotei.cerm.ru/student/train/"+rule_id,
           "Cookie": cookie,
           "Connection": "keep-alive"}
 
headers2 = headers
headers2["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
 
y = 0
while y < 5:
    #получение заданий
    r = requests.post("http://gramotei.cerm.ru/student/train/"+rule_id+"/new", headers = headers)
    f = r.json()
 
    lol = []
    n = 8
 
    for lts in f["words"]:
        SaveDate = '{"id":'+json.dumps(lts["id"])+',"rule_id":'+json.dumps(lts["rule"])+',"status":"correct"}'
        lol.append(json.loads(SaveDate, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict))
 
        if(n <= 0):
            data = "data="+json.dumps(lol)
            print(data)
 
            #отправка предварительного отчета чезез GET
            url = "http://gramotei.cerm.ru/App/Teacher/ajax.php?save_words=ok&ex_id="+rule_id+"&saving=0&data="+json.dumps(lol)
            SaveGet = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
            print(SaveGet.status_code, " ", SaveGet.text)
 
            #отправка отчета чезез POST
            SavePOST = requests.post("http://gramotei.cerm.ru/student/saveResult/"+rule_id, headers = headers2, data = data)
            print(SavePOST.status_code, " ", SavePOST.text)
        else:
            n=n-1
```

Вот код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cod.py", line 30, in <module>
    f = r.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: проверьте, что в ```r```?

Comment: скорее всего cookie просрочены и r.status_code = 404 (4хх)